# How to write a Rails model relation scope as efficiently as possible

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User and a Payment model. User has many Payments and a Payment has one User. For figuring out if user has a valid payment, I use this:

User.rb

```
def payment_active?
  payments.where("? >= made_at and ? <= valid_until", DateTime.now, DateTime.now).any?
end
```

I'd like to define a scope that returns users with active payments and I've come up with this:

User.rb

```
def self.active_users
  User.all.select {|u| u.payment_active?}
end
```

What would be the appropriate, more efficient way to write such a scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
scope :with_active_payments, ->(datetime = nil) {
  includes(:payments).where('payments.made_at >= :now AND :now <= payments.valid_until', now: datetime || DateTime.current)
}
```

- Using `DateTime.current` to properly use your current Time Zone.
- Using `.joins(:payments)` (instead of includes) can make the scope returning a non-uniq list of users
- You can either pass a datetime to this scope instead of using now: `User.with_active_payments(DateTime.current - 1.months)`

Answer (score 2):

As GSP said for ActiveRecord or use the following query for Mongoid:

```
User.where( :id.in => Payment.where(:made_at <= DateTime.now, :valid_until >= DateTime.now).distinct(:user_id) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a inner join against the `payments` table.  This might work:

```
User.joins(:payments).where('payments.made_at <= ? and payments.valid_until >= ?', DateTime.now, DateTime.now)
```

As a scope, it might look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :active_users, -> {
    joins(:payments).where('payments.made_at <= ? and payments.valid_until >= ?', DateTime.now, DateTime.now)
  }

end
```

Comment: This does not return a list of uniq users. Using the joins can duplicate records in the resulting array. Use `.includes(:payments)` instead.

Comment: MyYoshiji has a point. If your data includes users who have made multiple payments (e.g they are "double active") then that user would be returned once for each time they meet the criteria.